# How to enable the browser for camera access?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hi currently i am working with camera API for Chrome browser. But my Browser is not supporting navigation.getUserMedia.

Hi sharing some piece of code for this.

This is MY HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>getUserMedi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="video-container">
  <video id="camera-stream" width="500" autoplay></video>
  </div>
  <script src="camera.js">
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now Here My CSS file:

```
  body {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
        }

   #video-container {
   margin: 2em auto 0;
   width: 500px;
   padding: 2em;
   background: white;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #D9D9D9;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #D9D9D9;
   -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #D9D9D9;
   -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #D9D9D9;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #D9D9D9;
        }
```

Here camera.js file:

```
    window.onload = function() {

    // Normalize the various vendor prefixed versions of getUserMedia.
   navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
   navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
   navigator.msGetUserMedia);

   if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  // Request the camera.
   navigator.getUserMedia(
    // Constraints
    {
    video: true
    },

    // Success Callback
    function(localMediaStream) {
     // Get a reference to the video element on the page.
    var vid = document.getElementById('camera-stream');

    // Create an object URL for the video stream and use this 
    // to set the video source.
    vid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
                 },

         // Error Callback
    function(err) {
    // Log the error to the console.
    console.log('The following error occurred when trying to use  
     getUserMedia: ' + err);           
              }
           );

        } else {
        alert('Sorry, your browser does not support getUserMedia');
            }
            };
```

Here My Camera is not able to turn on. And browser Is also not supporting Please clarify about this guy's.

Comment: This is working as expected. I just had to remove the line break in the console log inside the error callback function. [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gn94bngg/)

Comment: Just saw that `getUserMedia()` no longer works on insecure origins. Take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/Dsoq5xPdzyw/21znuLWVCgAJ) and [here](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins). So, maybe this is why it is not working for you in chrome on an insecure origin.

Comment: jsfiddle – DavidDomain i had removed but i am not getting accepted output.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: can you give some possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `navigation.getUserMedia` is deprecated and no longer supported by most Browsers.

The new recommended API as found on Mozilla.org website is `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Please, you can read more by via the URL below.

[Media Devices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices)

[API For Camera Access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)